# Constructing Python Class

Tags: python, class

I'm new to python and a total noob with programming so bear with.

If I was building show Person class

```
    class Person:
      def __init__ (self, Name, Address, Phone, Height, Weight):
        self.name = Name
        self. Address = Address
        self.Phone = Phone
        self.Height = Height
        self.Weight = Weight
        self.PoundserPerInch = int(Height) / int(Weight)
```

what exactly does the `__init__()` function do for the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__init__` method is the constructor. It contains code that is run for each object that is created from that class. It contains code to initialize the object in a proper state.

In your case, you have a `Person` class which can be used to create `Person` objects. If you would write:

```
p = Person('John', '10 Foo Street', '1234567890', 70, 180)
```

it will create a `Person` object with those initial values. The constructor takes the values that you passed and it'll assign them to the variables of that object. It will also compute a value called `PoundserPerInch`.

Comment: Whilst `__init__()` is commonly called the "constructor", it actually isn't.  It's called after the instance has been constructed, which is passed as the `self` argument.  The actual constructor is `__new__()`.